# Custom observable collection android

Tags: java, android, data-binding, collections

I just came over the beta *Databinding* library on Android. I went through the developer's guide, yet, I am still uncertain, how to bind, for instance, a spinner to custom collection. The question is, if it is even possible.

---

Here are steps to make all things work.

- Create a class that extends ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback.
- Custom collection, that we want to bind to the spinner (or other adapterbased view) should extend ObservableList(or its' siblings) and have the addOnListChangedCallback (onListChangedCallback olcc).
- Create a custom adapter that works with our custom collection.
  ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback should notify the adapter at events, we want to listen.
- Create, written in developer's guide, annotations to xml of corresponding view: import + variable in the data section and app:adapter= by the spinner.
- Create custom static setter for our custom adapter using @BindingAdapter() annotation.

Comment: Did you try out anything?

Comment: Yes, i am currently examing, if i can use databinding with 'android:entries = "@{some_collection}"'

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html - This guide is pretty clear on how to do stuff. There is also a paragraph dealing with observables.

Comment: There is nothing said about custom collections, neither about binding a spinner to a collection, or some other adapter-based view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>`Spinner` doesn't have an attribute `android:entries` so that isn't how to bind a value to a Spinner.</s> I was wrong about that, even though I implemented it!

The entries attribute takes an array of `CharSequence`. If you want it to take an arbitrary collection:

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:entries"})
public static void setEntries(AbsSpinner view, List<String> entries) {
    if (entries != null) {
        SpinnerAdapter oldAdapter = view.getAdapter();
        boolean changed = true;
        if (oldAdapter != null && oldAdapter.getCount() == entries.size()) {
            changed = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++) {
                if (!entries.get(i).equals(oldAdapter.getItem(i))) {
                    changed = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (changed) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                            entries.toArray(new String[entries.size()]);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            view.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    } else {
        view.setAdapter(null);
    }
}
```

You should probably use an `ObservableList` instead of `List` and add a listener that updates your ArrayAdapter every time the values change.

Because it is an `AdapterView`, you'd typically use the `setAdapter()` method. Therefore, you can use the automatically generated attribute `app:adapter="@{myAdapter}"` to use the `setAdapter()` method.

If you want to use a custom attribute like "entries", you can create one using a `BindingAdapter`. Inside a class in your application -- doesn't matter which class, but by convention these are grouped by the target View type:

```
public class SpinnerAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter("entries")
    public static void setEntries(Spinner view, final List<String> values) {
        SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter() {
            // Use values to implement the SpinnerAdapter
        }
        view.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    }
}
```

If you want to use a custom collection, replace List<String> with whatever your custom collection type is. If you want it to be observable, Adapter supports data change notifications, so make sure to add a listener to whatever list you provide (e.g. `ObservableList`) and notify the adapter change.

Comment: Ofcourse it does! Spinner extends AbsSpinner, which has the "entries" attribute. But this doesnt make answer wrong. I'll try it out aswell

Comment: @GeorgeMount can you please help me. that how can I use this for FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: @GeorgeMount I have been wondering how to use the ObservableList for creating entries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881669/android-how-do-you-bind-observablelist-to-spinner-entries